# Understanding a step in the proof that the Whitehead product $[]$ has order $n.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Here is the first part of the proof:

> [$H_{i}$ for $i<4$ and $H_{4}$ on different domains.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPlbY.png)

Could you please tell me how we applied Kunneth theorem here in details?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about the [relative Künneth Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583698/relative-version-of-kunneth-theorem-for-cw-pairs) applied to two copies of $(X,\ast)$?

Comment: I think so @Tyrone. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [It seems you are] asking about the [relative Künneth Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583698/relative-version-of-kunneth-theorem-for-cw-pairs) applied to two copies of $(X,\ast)$. -- Tyrone.